# How to keep track of time client and server side PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I will be building an exam system using Laravel Framework (PHP). Where students are able to take exams, but with a time constrain. For example if the exam was to start at 13:00 (my time) and goes for 2 hours. Therefore it will end at 15:00. If a client was to access the exam, How would I able to sync the time between client and server?

Thank you.

Comment: if you want the client side to have awareness of the expiration time, the easiest way possible is probably to track the remaining duration in a server-side variable, and then add that duration to the `Date.now()` value of the client side on page load. Removing the time-zone issue. The server will need to be the source of truth since the client-side can be manipulated. Be aware that PHP tracks time in seconds and JS tracks it in milliseconds. Hope that helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
use Carbon\Carbon;
public function examtime()
{  
   $end_time = Carbon::now()->addHours(2);
   $start_time = Carbon::now();
     if (carbon::now() === $end_time) {
             // close exam 
            }
     }
```